# Tool bar not show in table view landscape mode 'ipad'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I crate table view programmatically with toolBar and navigation Bar. I want to my table view covered and scroll in all device and oriention. but my code wrong and table view not covered view and not scroll.
Tanks for your Help.

```
self.letterTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0,44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height), style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
        self.letterTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "chooseReciverTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        self.letterTableView.delegate = self
        self.letterTableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(letterTableView)
let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))
        let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "letter")
        navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height-44, view.bounds.width, 44)
 self.view.addSubview(navBar)
         self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

Comment: use autolayout please

Comment: @Shubhank how use it ?

Comment: try going through its tutorial videos on youtube or check this written series https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1, You just create constraints in your view so that the view adjust its frame itself for orientations and size